# EbaySDK Python GetFeedback (ItemID) only returning 100 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, ebay-api

I am using ebaysdk for Python. I am using the Trading API to GetFeedback for items (based on ItemID) with `'DetailsLevel': 'ReturnAll'`. I only want to get feedback that was left for the seller, but the returning data majorly contains feedback left for the Buyer and the response is limited to a 100 entries only.
More specifically, it is returning "Feedback Left For Others".

Following is my code:

```
api2 = Trading(config_file='ebay.yaml')
response2=api2.execute('GetFeedback',{'ItemID':'153221482165', 'Role':'Seller', 'DetailLevel':'ReturnAll'}).dict()
print(response2)
```

Is there a way to filter my response to "Seller Feedback" only, and for the API to return All data instead of the first 100 entries.

My Python version is 3.7.0

Comment: Please ignore the 'Role': 'Seller' in the API call.
I was just doing trying something, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

You should read carefully EBAY API [GetFeedback documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetFeedback.html)

If You only need feedback left for seller, try

`FeedbackType.FeedbackReceivedAsSeller`

For pagination, it seems that with ItemId You can't get more than 100 results at once:

> Unique identifier for an eBay item listing. A listing can have multiple order line items, but only one ItemID. If ItemID is specified in the GetFeedback request, the returned Feedback record(s) are restricted to the specified ItemID. The maximum number of Feedback records that can be returned is 100.
>   Max length: 19 (Note: ItemIDs are usually 9 to 12 digits).

Cheers

Comment: I actually did read the ebaysdk documentation. FeedbackType.FeedbackReceivedAsSeller does not return any data for me at all.

Moreover, Pagination does not work with GetFeedback if you search it on the basis of ItemID, according to the ebaysdk documentation.

Comment: You're right, I am trying to push You to read docs carefully but i didn't myself :/ My bad. With ItemId : "The maximum number of Feedback records that can be returned is 100." Otherwise are You sure that feedback for seller is not zero ? I receive correct results ( although we use feedback for all items, thus my pagination "lazy" notice)